# how to capture a bitmap from a view with its parent background

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to create a bitmap from a view and have the bitmap contain the background from the parent view(s).

The following code will capture the View "v":

```
  v.buildDrawingCache();
  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap (v.getDrawingCache());
```

But the background will be only that of "v".  In this case, "v" has a transparent background, so "b" has a transparent alpha channel.  I want "b" to contain the actual displayed background.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest you the following solution. As you can have several parents with semitransparent backgrounds you can capture whole activity window and then crop the part that you need (your view bounds).

For example:

```
    View root = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    root.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    root.buildDrawingCache();
    // here you got whole screen bitmap
    Bitmap screenshot = root.getDrawingCache();

    // get view coordinates
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationInWindow(location);

    // crop the screenshot
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenshot, location[0], location[1], view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), null, false);
```

After doing this you can be always sure that your bitmap contains the actual displayed background.

**UPD:** If `root.getDrawingCache()` doesn't work you can capture the screen just by directly drawing it on bitmap:

```
    View root = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(root.getWidth(), root.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(screenshot);
    root.draw(canvas);
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this after posting the question.  It fails because buildDrawingCache() returns null for large views.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer and added another way how you can capture big view without using `buildDrawingCache()`. Anyway it looks like it is the only way to achieve what you want - capture whole screen and crop it.

Comment: Your second solution sounds good.  So, does calling root.draw() recursively draw the entire view hierarchy, including realizing layouts?

Comment: Yes, it will recursively draw entire view hierarchy. That's actually how Android system itself is performing drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Try `v.getBackground()`

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),v.getBackground());
```

Comment: That will only draw the view's background, not the parent view's background.  In my case, it's the parent's background I'm trying to capture.  Yes, I can go through the view hierarchy and have each view draw to a bitmap but I'm trying to avoid that.